# What is the best approach to change the views in Ext JS ? Card layout or add/remove?

Tags: extjs

We have an application where we have the tree nodes panel left side , on click of each node we have an requirement to display different views.Which could be the best way to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends (which is the reason why both ways are available).

If you want to keep the state of the views, use card layout. If you want to always start fresh when a node is clicked, use add/remove.

If you use global ids, and have multiple tree nodes that need the same view, but with different data, you would possibly be forced to either use add/remove or refactor the global ids away.